# How to define a pst(outlook) file path so that i can get my calendar item

Tags: vb.net

I mange to retrive my calander items from my outlook calander like that:

```
    Dim objOLApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim objSubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objCalenderItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim objOutlookFolders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim intFolderCtr As Integer
    Dim intSubFolderCtr As Integer
    Dim intAppointmentCtr As Integer

    objOLApp = New Outlook.Application
    objOutlookFolders = objOLApp.Session.Folders

    For intFolderCtr = 1 To objOutlookFolders.Count
        objFolder = objOutlookFolders.Item(intFolderCtr)
        objExplorer = objFolder.GetExplorer()
        For intSubFolderCtr = 1 To objExplorer.CurrentFolder.Folders.Count
            objSubFolder = objExplorer.CurrentFolder.Folders.Item(intSubFolderCtr)
            If objSubFolder.DefaultItemType = Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem Then
                For intAppointmentCtr = 1 To objSubFolder.Items.Count
                    objCalenderItem = objSubFolder.Items.Item(intAppointmentCtr)
                    Call Debug.Print(objCalenderItem.Subject & ", " & objCalenderItem.Location)

                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

The problem is outlook interope does that automaticly from my psd.
Say i want to point out the path of the pst file... 
Can someone please tell me how?

Comment: There are several things wrong with the code. Most glaringly, you use 1-based loops but the arrays are 0-based. This will result in runtime errors. Furthermore, you should use `For Each` loops here instead of bare `For` loops. Finally, your question isn’t clear at all. What do you want to do? Where is the problem? How does your code relate to this?

Comment: My code is not related to this at all... i put it there in the name of sharing. This code retrive the information from my on outlook pst file without me telling him where is the file. I want to tell him where are the file so i can retrive calander items from sevral pst files

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use the _Store interface in the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook which represents a file on the local computer or a network drive that stores e-mail messages and other items for an account in the current profile.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.store.aspx

And Konrad, I have a feeling that in at least the Outlook automation world the indexes start at one, hence those loops start at one too.